# pre-commit vs tox | what's the difference | scope of use

Tags: python, continuous-integration, tox, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Tox:
https://tox.wiki/en/latest/

pre-commit:
https://pre-commit.com/

I would like to understand the borders for both choices.

I know that pre-commit creates a py environment - same as tox. To me, their architecture looks a bit the same.

Some people use them in combination... what pre-commit can't do, that tox can? I saw examples where with pre-commit during CI pipeline you can run unit tests, etc.

Which one is the best to integrate within the CI build?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, `pre-commit` is a linter/formatter runner, `tox` is a generic virtual env management and test command line tool.

While `tox` could run linters too, it is tedious to manage the versions of the linters. In `pre-commit` you can just run `pre-commit autoupdate`, and all linters get updated.

On the other hand `tox` can run e.g. a test suite or a coverage report for many different Python versions. This is not only helpful for a library, but also for an app - so you can already test the upcoming Python versions.

`tox` is also used to create documentation, and sometimes also to make a release - you can't (shouldn't) do this with `pre-commit`.

And `tox` is certainly not obsolete, although GitHub actions can test against different Python versions, as you can run `tox` both local and in CI.

I gave a lightning talk on this topic:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnM3KuE7MQM

> Which one is the best to integrate within the CI build?

I like to run `pre-commit` via `tox`, both in CI and locally.

### Example tox configuration

https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/6496f8427a06be4a9f6a5699757ca7f9aba78ef6/tox.ini#L24-L26

### Example pre-commit configuration

https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/6496f8427a06be4a9f6a5699757ca7f9aba78ef6/.pre-commit-config.yaml